# Issue with IAM, MFA Policy in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

From the [AWS documentatio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_my-sec-creds-self-manage-mfa-only.html)n, I implement an IAM Policy for MFA authentication for the IAM users. After attaching this policy to the users, though, they are unable to access the s3 buckets through the AWS console.

"Policy defines that, Unless the user is signed into the AWS console with MFA, all actions will be denied, except for managing the user's personal IAM account and MFA settings. IAM users does not have an MFA device assigned."

Status:
"Assigned MFA device = Not assigned | Manage”

**example Policy attached**

```
{
            "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
```

IAM users is facing the issue, when they tried setting up MFA it gave them an error about permissions.

> “Entity already exists This entity already exists. Learn more
> • MFADevice entity at the same path and name already exists. Before
> you can add a new virtual MFA device, ask your administrator to delete
> the existing device using the CLI or API.”

and

> "Insufficient permissions to list objects After you or your AWS
> administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:ListBucket
> action, refresh the page. Learn more about Identity and access
> management in Amazon S3 "

I already tried [Enabling a virtual multi-factor authentication (**MFA**) device (console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_enable_virtual.html),
But unable to fix the issue.

If you know anything, I'd be happy to let you know.

Thank you!

Comment: The first error message has nothing to do with permissions. It's saying that the MFA device in question has already been configured and cannot be re-added.

Comment: Adding that policy would cause problems with S3 and other resources, so I removed it, and now want to add the MFA IAM Policy without affecting resources.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve the desired result through this IAM Policy :
IAM policy that allows IAM users to self-manage an MFA device. This policy provides the permissions necessary to complete this action using the AWS Console or AWS CLI .

**MFASelfManagedPolicy**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice",
                "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/${aws:username}",
                "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ListUsers"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_mfa-selfmanage.html